# How to bind Class with Google Guice using a FQDN String

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, guice

I'm using Play 2.5 with the Guice dependency injection.

Normal bind works like:

```
bind(classOf[SomeClass]).to(classOf[DefaultClass])
```

I now only need to be able to bind a class where the className has been specified in the Configuration.

I tried something like:

```
val className = config.getString("someClass.className")
val x: Class[_] = Class.forName(className)
bind(classOf[SomeClass]).to(classOf[x])
```

But then the types are wrong.

It needs to be done via Guice, since the `SomeClass` has an argument that needs to be injected, otherwise I would have used something like

```
val className = config.getString("someClass.className")
val x = Class.forName(className).newInstance().asInstanceOf[SomeClass]
bind(classOf[SomeClass]).toInstance(x)
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to bind it via guice?

Comment: Can't you cast it to be the right generic type? I don't know Scala, but in java `Class<SomeClass> clazz = (Class<SomeClass>)Class.forName(className); bind(SomeClass.class).to(clazz);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this...

```
lazy val injector = (new GuiceApplicationBuilder).injector()
def inject[T : ClassTag]: T = {
  injector.instanceOf[T]
}
```

This is the simplest version, but doesn't handle arguments. You would create a class and then call this as `inject[SomeDep]`.

I've not found a good way of injecting on-the-fly, the only way of really doing it via @inject at the top most invoked class. We only use inject for unit tests at present.

Comment: He's not looking to inject on the fly but to setup a binding that can be specified at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, but I finally got it to work using Scala's Reflection.

```
object Reflection {
  import scala.reflect.api
  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  import reflect.ClassTag

  def classTagToClass[T: reflect.ClassTag]: Class[T] = {
    def ctag = implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[T]]
    ctag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
  }

  def typeToClassTag[T: TypeTag]: ClassTag[T] = {
    ClassTag[T]( typeTag[T].mirror.runtimeClass( typeTag[T].tpe ) )
  }

  def stringToTypeTag[A](name: String): TypeTag[A] = {
    val c = Class.forName(name) // obtain java.lang.Class object from a string
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(c.getClassLoader) // obtain runtime mirror
    val sym = mirror.staticClass(name) // obtain class symbol for `c`
    val tpe = sym.selfType // obtain type object for `c`
    // create a type tag which contains above type object
    TypeTag(mirror, new api.TypeCreator {
      def apply[U <: api.Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]): U#Type =
        if (m eq mirror) {
          tpe.asInstanceOf[U#Type]
        }
        else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Type tag defined in $mirror cannot be migrated to other mirrors.")
        }
    })
  }
}
```

using the above object you can bind a class using it FQDN in the following way:

```
configuration.getString("config.className")
 .map(className =>
    bind(classOf[AbstractClass]).to(classTagToClass(typeToClassTag(stringToTypeTag[AbstractClass](className))))
 ).getOrElse(bind(classOf[AbstractClass]).to(classOf[AbstractClassImpl]))
```